# ASP.NET MVC C# Entity Convert to unknown type of unknown property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have to get the type of a property from an entity which is not known and then parse a string value to that I pass to the action.

Code sample:

```
public ActionResult QuickEdit(int pk, string name, string value)
{
    var pext = Db.ProjectExtensions.Find(pk); 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var propertyInfo = pext.GetType().GetProperty(name); //get property
        propertyInfo.SetValue(pext, value, null); //set value of property

        Db.SaveChangesWithHistory(LoggedEmployee.EmployeeId);

        return Content("");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it only works if the property is of type string. How can I parse value to the type of the property for which I am setting the value?

Thanks!

Update:

I tried:

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(pext, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

and i get

```
{"Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'."}
```

Comment: try setting  Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType) as 2nd parameter of SetValue

Comment: This code looks pretty dangerous, it lets you set any property on your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took ataravati's solution and modified it a bit to work with nullable types.

Here is the solution:

```
public ActionResult QuickEdit(int pk, string name, string value)
{
    var pext = Db.ProjectExtensions.Find(pk); 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var propertyInfo = pext.GetType().GetProperty(name); //get property
        if (propertyInfo != null)
                {
                    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType;
                    var safeValue = (value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(pext, safeValue, null);
                }
        Db.SaveChangesWithHistory(LoggedEmployee.EmployeeId);

        return Content("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (However, as DavidG mentioned in a comment, this let's you set any property on your model, and it's not a good idea):

```
public ActionResult QuickEdit(int pk, string name, string value)
{
    var pext = Db.ProjectExtensions.Find(pk); 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var propertyInfo = pext.GetType().GetProperty(name); //get property
        propertyInfo.SetValue(pext, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);

        Db.SaveChangesWithHistory(LoggedEmployee.EmployeeId);

        return Content("");
    }
}
```